# Tightly Coupled classes: what is better design in my situation

Tags: java, tightly-coupled-code

what is the better solution in my situation, how to design classes so they are not very coupled?

I have an Library (API) which provides some functionality (for example, subscribe for streaming FX prices with `subscribe` method). I have an API client, which tell to API which prices it want to get. API provides feedback with some interface (for example `SubscriptionStatus`) with methods `SubscribeSuccess(Subscription) and SubscribeFailed(Subscription)`. In API client I have a list of active subscriptions (`List<Subscription> activeSubscriptions`).  And I want API client only react on subscription success (just add subscription into list). In other cases - just print message to log.
What is the best way to organize relations between Subscription listener and API Client? 
Options could be:

1. Pass API client instance to the subscription listener so it can call `apiClient.addSubscription(subscription)`
2. API client implement implement `SubscriptionStatus` interface and manage those events (fail, success internally: activeSubscriptions.add(subscription)). Contra: There are a lot of types of actions and every action has it's own listener.. So Api Client will be really big class.
3. Define own interface with one method `SubscriptionSuccess(subscription)` and let API client implement it?
4. Your option?

Any thoughts on topic are appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go option 2, with a catch. If the `SubscriptionStatus` interface is really really big, and you know some clients only want to implement part of that, you can provide a base empty superclass, and you let clients extend it (make it `abstract` to force them)

Something like `BaseSubscriptionStatus` that has empty implementations for all methods, and let the user override the ones it wants. Another option is to

```
throw UnsupportedOperationException("This method is not supported by your implementation of SubscriptionStatus. Please override it");
```

for each base method instead of the empty implementation.

Of course, you can keep the `SubscriptionStatus` interface for proper dependency injection and testability, only make `BaseSubscriptionStatus` implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option two. This would give the end use the most flexibility and be able to respond to issues with the streaming more effectively in their situation.